# Filter by Portfolio Item Type

Tags: javascript, extjs4, rally

It looks like the attribute on a portfolio item called "Portfolio Item Type" has values which are objects, just like the "State" attribute. However, I am not sure how I would go about using that attribute as a filter, just like the dropdown that is available on the Portfolio Items page.*

I tried binding to the values with radio buttons, which does not work. So, would I need to use an attribute/object dropdown instead?

*I also noticed that the "Type" label on the left of that dropdown disappears when switching from "Initiative" or "MRU" to the other, after the initial page load.

Edit: It looks like I can use an attribute dropdown for the "State" attribute, but not the "Portfolio Item Type." I have also tried changing it to an object dropdown to no avail.

Here's an example of the javascript I'm trying to use:

```
var typeDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.AttributeDropdown({
    defaultValue : "Initiative",
    label:"Type",
    showLabel:true,
    type : "PortfolioItem",
    attribute : "PortfolioItemType"
}, rallyDataSource);

typeDropdown.display("typeDropdown", dropdownSelectionChanged);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rally SDK 1.x you can use the following to display a dropdown of Portfolio Item types  ...

```
var type_config = { label : "Select type: " , type : "Type", attribute : "Name",fetch : "Name,ObjectID"  } ;

var objectDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ObjectDropdown(type_config, rallyDataSource);
objectDropdown.display("pi-type", typeChanged);
```

Portfolio Item types are distinct objects (instances of 'Type') as they contain additional information (ordinal number, kanban states etc.).

Comment: If you are using App SDK 2.x there is an example here https://github.com/RallyApps/PortfolioKanban/blob/master/PortfolioKanbanApp.js#L32

Comment: Thanks Barry - should have realized the collection was a group of object ref's! This avoids the whole radio button procedure completely!

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, Barry. Perhaps this is something that could be made apparent in the documentation on the Rally dev site?

Comment: Apologies for the run-around, BTW.

Comment: Actually, I believe this solution is specific to SDK 1.3, and not just 1.x. No worries Mark. It was intriguing. I wish I could have figured out why your solution wasn't working within my own code, though. :)